# whith gevent joinablequeue, how to tell the queue a task is not done?

Tags: python, queue, task, gevent

My task can fail, and in that case, i would like to kill the worker, and put back the element in queue so that another worker can do the job.

How to do that ?

```
def worker():
  while 1:
    item=q.get()
    try:
       ataskthatcanfail(item)
    except:
      break
    else:
      q.task_done()
```

Comment: Maybe i should tell the queue it's done and reinsert the item in the queue ?